# iPad Pro Won't Turn On

Tags: ipad, power

iPad Pro was fully charged. Upon going to bed I set alarms as usual. No alarm in morning and iPad will not turn on. When I try to recharge the back gets quite warm. I tried restarting by pushing both home and power buttons for over 1 minute with no luck. I plugged it into computer with iTunes and still nothing. What next?

Comment: take the battery out, then put it in again

Comment: @Buscar웃 - and how do you propose RMc goes about taking the battery out of an iPad Pro?

Comment: @IconDaemon difficult process I know, there are many instructions how to, so just Google it.

Comment: Leave it on charge for at least 2 hours.  Is your device still under warranty or under Apple Care?  You should take it back to Apple.  I'm sure you have everything in iCloud, or a similar backup, so you should be able to get your data back if they have to replace the device.

Comment: @Buscar웃 - yes, I know it is difficult, even for a trained technician like myself. Seeing that Apple will replace a battery for US$99 (+shipping) that seems a whole lot less expensive than replacing the entire iPad because it was damaged whilst trying to repair it oneself.

Comment: You should visit [this page at Apple Support](https://support.apple.com/ipad/repair/battery-power) for options on how to have the battery replaced in your iPad by Apple. If you consider yourself technically able to replace the battery yourself, (and have the requisite tools,) go for it! It is a very satisfying experience when you snap it back together and it just works.